# CKEditor issue: How to apply custom css to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I want to have all styles applied to my `CKEditor` content. So main idea is to make editor look like actual page.

I've added this to my `config.js` file

```
config.contentsCss = '/Home/GetCss';
```

And I have a server-side action which is getting css file from database and returning it to me.

```
public ActionResult GetCss()
{
  var settings = GetSettings();
  return File(settings.CssContent, "text/css", settings.CssFileName);
}
```

After that I can see that my css is included in head(inside ckeditor iframe) of ckeditor, but styles doesn't apply to content.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Home/GetCss">
```

What can cause this issue?

***EDIT: (after seeing couple of answers)***

Please answer only when you know what can be a real problem... GetCss is returining right css and next css including line is auto-generated with `config.contentsCss = '/Home/GetCss';` . So the issue is somewhere in **CKEditor** settings, not with the server-side function and generated code.

**EDIT 2:**

After setting css file directly the issue remains the same

```
config.contentsCss = '/Content/MyCssFile.css';
```

Still I can see correct css file in iframe's HEAD part, but no afect to body elements.

Comment: you mean you want to add your css to ckeditor ?

Comment: Yes, I want to apply css file styles to ckeditor's inner html.

Comment: is ckeditor striping class off from div or span while toggeling `view source` mode?

Comment: A suggestion: Comment out your logic for injecting .css file. Try making changes in the default CSS file that comes with CKEditor and see if the changes get applied ?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue with machine running Php (So I can only help with figuring out the problem). Styles are applied only when right content-type header is set (`Content-Type: text/css`) for css request. Check for it in developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using inline editing instead of the classic version which is using iframes?

The advantage of the inline version is that if, for example, your CSS heavily relies on the hierarchy of elements, it will work definitely better without iframes. Have a look at this code:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    (Here goes the content that is edited inside CKEditor)
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#main #container h2 {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#07c;
}
```

The style for the header will most likely not be recognized inside the classic CKEditor, even if you try to use things like [config.bodyId](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-bodyId), because this way you could fake only one ID: "main" or "container" by adding such ID to the body element.

The inline version will not have this limitation, because the content will not be encapsulated inside the iframe.

One more thing: if the reason why "styles doesn't apply to content" is indeed in the hierarchy of elements inside CSS and you want to use the "old" classic version, you may simply consider providing a dedicated, simplified stylesheet to the editor. Start with the most simple CSS to see if you're on the right path.

Comment: Actually, the problem was in header classes in real document... Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Home/GetCss">
```

if the folder home lies in the root directory then this be your href link.

Comment: This is autogenerated by CKEditor

Comment: I am trying same but it's not working. I am storing CK Editor generated code in MySQL 'blob' and when I am displaying that on my page it showing same as it is in database. I am trying to apply custom CSS style but it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: @Abdullah did you add css extension yourfile.css ?

Comment: yes. I linked it <link>

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   public string GetCss()
 {/*
     var settings = GetSettings();
    return Url.Content(settings.CssContent);*/
   return Url.Content("~/path_to_css");
  }
```

and

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Action("GetCss", "Home")">
```

Comment: No, second line is auto-generated and loading css well... I can see in Console.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom file "ckeditor_config.js" and put your styles inside. look this article:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations

To import css file use this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Home/GetCss")" />
```

Cause url content get the path absolute of te application.

Comment: Css line is auto-generated by CKEditor

Answer (score 0):

Try `CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet`. I use something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.domReady(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('editorDiv', {
                docType: '<!DOCTYPE html>',
                on: {
                    instanceReady: function (ev) {
                        var editor = ev.editor;

                        // add editable content CSS
                        editor.document.appendStyleSheet(
                            '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetCss")');

                        // ... more editor instance initialization code
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```